# Merge linked list in to one list

Tags: c#, linked-list, lambda

I am trying to return a List but am having trouble with the following List

I have used the following lambda expression to generate a string list

```
      var lstItems = rows.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

note: 'rows' is kind of linked list ie, **LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryable<'LinqToExcel.Row'>**

Input list as follows:

```
  rows      cell
  [0] ------[0]  {"myValue1"}
            [1]  {1}
            [2]  {"abc"}
  [1] ------[0]  {"myValue2"}
            [1]  {1}
            [2]  {"pqr"}
  [2] ------[0]  {"myValue3"}
            [1]  {5}
            [2]  {"ppp"}
  and so on..
```

The result list expects is as follows

```
      List<string> lstItems = [0] - {"myValue1"}
                              [1] - {1}
                              [2] - {"abc"}
                              [3] - {"myValue2"}
                              [4] - {1}
                              [5] - {"pqr"}
                              [6] - {"myValue3"}
                              [7] - {5}
                              [8] - {"ppp"}
```

The result list would be cell values of all rows to be merged in one list and it should be in the given input-ed row - cell order.

The desired output i can achieve through the following code:

```
    List<string> lstExcelData = new List<string>();
    foreach (LinqToExcel.Row row in rows)
    {
        foreach (LinqToExcel.Cell cell in row)
        {
            lstExcelData.Add(cell.Value.ToString().Trim());
        }
    }
```

But if possible by lambda expression is much better as i always like to go with lambda expression for iteration.

Comment: Can you please provide us with a small sample input data and the desired output format of that data?

Comment: @samar : modified the question, mentioned the input and output

Answer (score 1):

To be absolutely honest with you, I have never used `LinqToExcel` so I do not know the classes, properties etc inside it so please do not downvote this answer. :) Provide feedback and I will try to improve it if possible.

```
        List<string> lstExcelData = new List<string>();

        lstExcelData = rows.SelectMany(row => row.Select(cell => cell.Cast<string>())).ToList();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryable<'LinqToExcel.Row'> does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' accepting a first argument of type 'LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryable<'LinqToExcel.Row'>' could be found. 
I was trying to cast the "rows" in to a known type, but didn't work well.. :(

Comment: 'LinqToExcel.Row' (ie, row ) does not contain  definition for 'Cells' and no extension method 'Cells' accepting a first argument of type 'LinqToExcel.Row' could be found

Comment: :( sorry...  Parser exception thrown...

Could not parse expression 'value(LinqToExcel.Query.ExcelQueryable`1[LinqToExcel.Row]).SelectMany(row => row.Select(cell => cell.Cast()))': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.SelectMany' is currently not supported, but you can register your own parser if needed.

Comment: Am sure that your answer should work in the real linked list scenario rather than LinqToExcel list. Appreciate your help and quick response. Up vote your last answer without mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var lstItems = rows.Select((row,index) => new {
                                          Cells = row.Select(x => x.ToString())
                                                     .ToList(),
                                          RowIndex = index
                                              }).ToList();
```

That gives you all Rows with Cell values, for example you can access  second `Cell` value of a third `Row` like this:

```
var value = lstItems[2].Cells[1];
```